# Получить список внешних сетевых интерфейсов и заполнить ими массив выпадающего списка

Tags: java, android, сеть, android-spinner

Удалось получить список сетевых интерфейсов, не получается загнать их в спиннер (выпадающий список).

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView textView;
EditText editText;
Button button;
Spinner spinnerNet;
String tag;
String editString;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
    textView = findViewById(R.id.tv);
    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    spinnerNet = findViewById(R.id.spinnerNetwork);

    getNetworkInterfaces();

}

public void getNetworkInterfaces () {

    String str = "";
    try {

    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
            "ls /sys/class/net");

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            process.getInputStream()));
    int i;
    char[] buffer = new char[4096];
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

    while ((i = reader.read(buffer)) > 0)
        output.append(buffer, 0, i);
    reader.close();

    // body.append(output.toString()+"\n");
    str = output.toString();


    Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinnerNetwork);

    //Здесь ругается на массив str
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Integer.parseInt(str));

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // body.append("Error\n");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

}
```

Код ошибки

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: ru.nag.testtask, PID: 25641

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ru.nag.testtask/ru.nag.testtask.ui.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: 
ccmni0
ccmni1
ccmni2
ifb0
ifb1
ip6tnl0
lo
p2p0
sit0
tunl0
wlan0
"
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2534)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2614)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5643)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)

Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: 
"ccmni0
ccmni1
ccmni2
ifb0
ifb1
ip6tnl0
lo
p2p0
sit0
tunl0
wlan0
"
at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:410)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:367)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
at ru.nag.testtask.ui.activity.MainActivity.getNetworkInterfaces(MainActivity.java:81)
at ru.nag.testtask.ui.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6100)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
                                                                        ... 10 more
11-13 17:30:40.599 25641-25641/ru.nag.testtask I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 25641 SIG: 9
```

Comment: ip  l l покажет все, в sys/class/net тоже все. А выключенные по rfkill или как?

Comment: Имеется ввиду на подобии NetworkInterface.isUp или как то по другому. Чтобы было видно, включен ли сетевой интерфейс или нет

Comment: вот я и говорю `ip link list` и смотри up,lower_up

Answer (score 0):

Давно, правда, писал, но должно работать:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <net/if.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int get_iface_list(struct ifconf *ifconf)
{
   int sock, rval;

   sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
   if(sock < 0)
   {
     perror("socket");
     return (-1);
   }

   if((rval = ioctl(sock, SIOCGIFCONF , (char*) ifconf  )) < 0 )
     perror("ioctl(SIOGIFCONF)");

   close(sock);

   return rval;
}

int main()
{
   static struct ifreq ifreqs[20];
   struct ifconf ifconf;
   int  nifaces, i;

   memset(&ifconf,0,sizeof(ifconf));
   ifconf.ifc_buf = (char*) (ifreqs);
   ifconf.ifc_len = sizeof(ifreqs);

   if(get_iface_list(&ifconf) < 0) return -1;

   nifaces =  ifconf.ifc_len/sizeof(struct ifreq);

   printf("Interfaces (count = %d)\n", nifaces);
   for(i = 0; i < nifaces; i++)
   {
     printf("\t%-10s\n", ifreqs[i].ifr_name);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если отталкиваться от sys, то состояние интерфейса можно посмотреть в

```
cat /sys/class/net/wlp2s0/carrier
```

1 - "провод" подключен

0 - провод не подключен

а с `carrier_changes` можно асинхронно тянуть события

Comment: получилось вывести список интерфейсов командой netcg. Как думаете, это нормальная практика?

Comment: я не спец по андроиду, не знаю во всех ли сборках эта команда присутствует